# How to get the proper element knowing the exact 'th' text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need to get the selected value from the select inside a big table only knowing the exact text of the `th` element before it. In the extract below, i need to get `One`, knowing only `check`. Any ideas?

```
<table>
    ....
    <tr>
        <th class="width2">check</th>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="">- Select -</option>
                <option value="1" selected="">One</option>
                <option value="2">two</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: jQuery does let you access the content for an element. Did you look it up? It's `.text()` I think.

Comment: Yes, i know i can do something like $('th:contains("check")'), but i can't get the select inside the td after the th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector but it select unwanted element in some cases.  So use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filtering `th` has special text.

```js
var t = $("th").filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == 'check';
}).next().find("select :selected").text();
console.log(t);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="width2">check</th>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="1" selected="">One</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```